# Enable Supermicro Virtualization in Bios

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, bios, supermicro

my motherboard is a Supermicro x9dri-ln4f+, and I am using dual xeon e5 2690 CPUs.

I have been trying to enable Virtualization in order to load VMs in qemu and virtualbox.

The motherboard claims to support VT-x,VT-d, and VT-c in the specs page, and the in the bios under cpu information, it states that all three of those are supported for the CPUs.

This issue is extremely similar to [enabling virtualization on supermicro board](https://serverfault.com/questions/844129/enabling-virtualization-on-supermicro-board?newreg=bbee705734b1413e92ffac88b8f720d8)
 but their solution of enabling NX(XF for me) did not fix anything, because it was already enabled.

Things I have done:

- Enabled ``
- Enabled `Intel VT-d` in `North Bridge->Integrated IO Configuration`
- Enabled `DCA` in `North Bridge->Integrated IO Configuration`
- Enabled `Isoc` in `North Bridge->QPI Configuration`
- Enabled `Execute-Disable Bit Capability`(Solution to other person's issue)
- Enabled `Intel Virtualization Technology` in `Advanced settings`
- Tried combinations of enabled `Prefetcher settings` in `advanced` such as `MLC Streamer, MLC Spatial, DCU Streamer, DCU IP`
- Tried settings bios to default settings and repeating above settings.
- Full boot and power cycle(completely off) after changing bios settings.

Additionally, from https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Activating_the_Intel_VT_Virtualization_Feature
 doing:

```
modprobe msr
rdmsr 0x3a
```

returns 0

Also running `dmesg`

```
$ dmesg | grep kvm
[    14.444265] kvm: disabled by bios
[    16.225445] kvm: disabled by bios
```

And in windows under cpu info in task manager it says that virtualization is disabled.

Any help is appreciated, as I have been racking my head for hours trying to get this to work.

Comment: You should select Restore Optimized Defaults, then select Save Changes and Reset. Do not change anything else (other than the boot order if necessary). Even if it doesn't work. Doing stuff at random isn't going to help, and virtualization works out of the box with the defaults. If it doesn't actually work, something else is going on.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Just tried that, and did a full power cycle(completely off). virtualization did not work when it turned back on. I haven't been doing things randomly, the last post from the first link referenced them possibly changing `page prefetch` but my bios dont have that kind of option. The rest of the settings were ones that I thought were a possible fix after reading the motherboard manual.

Comment: OK, now you can try to figure out why. Check `dmesg` and update your question if appropriate. You probably want to look for _any_ errors in `dmesg` at this point, not just trying to grep it for something. For instance with `dmesg --level=warn,err,crit,alert,emerg`

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is the output from running dmesg with your args https://pastebin.com/TzC9qY7Y It might be `secure boot`, but I dont remember there being any settings for that in the bios. There are also some `ACPI` errors, but I'm not sure it that should effect it. Thank you for your patience. Also `rdmsr 0x3a` now returns `1`

Comment: Well, get the obvious stuff out of the way first: Uninstall VirtualBox (how in hell did that even get there?). Check for system BIOS updates. I think you've got the latest BIOS but it doesn't hurt to double check. The "irq 16 nobody cared" should never happen and suggests you may have a hardware problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I removed VirtualBox(Not sure how that could change anything). The BIOS are the latest, and after adding irqpoll to boot options, it fixed the `irq 16 nobody cared` issue. New pastebin https://pastebin.com/UWzQ4WnD

Comment: What other hardware have you got installed on this board? I don't think that helped. I'm pretty sure there is an RMA in your future at this point...Er, wait, that board is old, you might not have that option.

Comment: I have a pcie sound card, wireless adapter, and RX 480 installed, and 64 GBs of ram installed, and a 750W Powersupply. At this point I dont think RMA is an option. Am I just out of luck? Do you think that I should try downgrading the bios if that is possible?

Comment: Eh? Just what sort of "server" is this?

Comment: Its more of a desktop with a server board and CPUs, but I was going to use it for hosting a few projects/render station.

Comment: Well, I would pull the sound card, wireless card and GPU back out, and try again. We might not be able to give you much of any help at this point.

Comment: Ill try that, Ill also try posting on some supermicro website if it still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOLVED] I fixed the issue by reinstalling the bios using IPMI instead of using a USB drive like before(Same Bios version). Then enabled ISOC in the north bridge settings. @MichaelHampton Thank you for your help